# Why does state not show a newly created empty object? Found workaround

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react 16.3.0-alpha.1 and having an issue adding an empty object, with the key "items", to a list object.

Addlist.js

```
createList = event => {
    //Stop form from submitting
    event.preventDefault();

   const list = {
       items: {},
       title: this.titleRef.current.value
   };
   this.props.addList(list); //This method lives in app.js

   // Clear the form after submitted
   event.currentTarget.reset();
};
```

App.js

```
state = {
    lists: {}
};

//Add new list with title and empty items object
addList = list => {

    // Take a copy of current state
    const lists = { ...this.state.lists };

    // Add new list to the lists collection
    lists[`${list.title}`] = list;

    console.log(lists);

    // Set the new lists collection to state
    this.setState({ lists: lists });
};
```

When the createList event fires it calls the addList method on app.js and passes the list object to the method. When I console log lists right before setState I can see that "list3" has been added with "items" and "title". But when I used the dev tools to view state it only shows the key "title" with its value. I also get an error stating that the key "items" on "list3" is null or undefined.

[image: console.log]

[image: state]

What am I doing wrong here? 
Does react remove empty objects on setState, is it a shallow copy problem, or something else?

---

So I found a workaround but I still don't know why I cant add an empty object.

For the workaround I changed list.items = {} to list.items = "" . The empty string did get added this time. Then later in a method where I add a new item to "list.items" I first checked to see if it was a string. If it was a string then I set "list.items" from a string to an empty object. This allowed me to continue adding nested objects. This step also happened right before setState.

Let me know if you know what caused this.

Comment: lists = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(lists)). please try it before setState

Comment: That code looks fine to me, can you share the render methods for both components?

Comment: @RIYAJ KHAN I tried the JSON.parse code and had no luck.

Comment: I would guess something w/ the alpha, as the latest, 16.2.0 works as you're expecting